# Data from a Column, only if another Column has the correct requirements, to go into Sheet 2

Tags: excel

I have a basic knowledge of excel, but I need more than basic to achieve what I'm trying to do. Here is what I'm trying to do.

Sheet 1 has 3 Columns - A) Price, B) Month, & C) Category

```
             Rows - Unlimited
```

Sheet 2 has 13 Columns - A) Creditor, B) Jan, C) Feb, D) Mar ....

```
             Rows - Unlimited
```

What I need is first of all is "Sheet 1, Column B (Month)" to go under the correct Column on "Sheet 2". Second, I want anything in "Sheet 1, Column A" to go into "Sheet 2, under the correct Month Column" only if the "Sheet 1, Column C" has the correct Category #.

I have try a lot of different types of formulas & functions that I can think of, but nothing will work.  As I said before, I have a very very very basic knowledge of excel.  Any help will be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct" Category #?
And what should we do with column A (Creditor) in sheet 2?

Comment: 1) Category # - I have #' 1 - 25 for the categories, 1 is rent, 2 is phone, 3 is water & elec,.....             2) Creditor - On Sheet 2, Column A is the list of creditors (which will be the catageories               so If I sheet 1 category is in the month of Jan then I want the Amount to go on sheet 2

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a [Pivot Table](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html).

Use the data in sheet 1 as its source, use the category for the rows, the month for the columns, and the sum of the `price`s for the content.

Initially you might get some (sub)totals you didn't ask for, but you can change that using the context menu.